# Opensuse 11.1 package manager outdated

Tags: opensuse, git, zypper

I'm trying to update GIT to the latest version. The package manager for opensuse 11.1 only has up to git 1.6.0.2. I'm updating using zypper:

```
 sudo zypper install git
```

And I get the following message:

```
 Loading repository data...
 Warning: Repository 'openSUSE-11.1-Update' appears to outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
 Reading installed packages...
 'git' is already installed.
 Resolving package dependencies...
 Nothing to do.
```

How do I change the repository URL for zypper and what should it be pointing to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason you are getting this message is that openSUSE 11.1 itself is outdated and no longer supported. It is unlikely that you will find a curren mirror for 11.1. If updating to a newer release of openSUSE is out of question, compiling git from source may be your best option.

Comment: Unfortunately installing from source run me into a number of problems since other libraries that the latest git required were out of date. It's not idea but it looks like I'll have to update the OS

Comment: Similar to [Why do I get "Warning: Repository 'oss_update' appears to be outdated"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433240).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you are going to probably have to upgrade if you don't want to install from source.

For future reference, you may want to try OpenSuSE [Tumbleweed](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed) or OpenSuSE [Evergreen](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Evergreen) as these repos provide continuous and long term support.