# Why do I get "Warning: Repository 'oss_update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server."?

Tags: opensuse, repository, zypper

On WSL, I executed `sudo zypper update`, but I got this error message.

> Loading repository data...
>   **Warning:** Repository 'oss_update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
>   Reading installed packages...
>
> Nothing to do.

When I executed `sudo zypper refresh`, I didn't get any error message, though.

```
Retrieving repository 'The Go Programming Language (openSUSE_Leap_42.3)' metadata ...............................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'devel:languages:php (openSUSE_Leap_42.3)' metadata .......................................................................................................................................................[done]
Repository 'oss' is up to date.
Retrieving repository 'oss_update' metadata .....................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving repository 'PHP7 extensions (php7_openSUSE_Leap_42.3)' metadata ......................................................................................................................................................[done]
All repositories have been refreshed
```

I checked the list of the repository I am using with `zypper lr -u`.

```
# | Alias                      | Name                                             | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | URI
--+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | devel_languages_go         | The Go Programming Language (openSUSE_Leap_42.3) | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/go/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/
2 | devel_languages_php        | devel:languages:php (openSUSE_Leap_42.3)         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/
3 | oss                        | oss                                              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/oss/suse/
4 | oss_update                 | oss_update                                       | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.3/oss/
5 | server_php_extensions_php7 | PHP7 extensions (php7_openSUSE_Leap_42.3)        | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No      | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/php:/extensions:/php7/php7_openSUSE_Leap_42.3/
```

When I check the content of http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.3/oss/, I see the files and the directories have been updated on March 23, 2018, so they don't seem obsolete.

Why am I getting that error message about the repository being outdated? How do I change the repository I am using? What should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer from https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/8fcbs5/update_of_opensuse_on_wsl_error/ : you need to change the repository URIs from HTTP to HTTPS. I just did that and was able to see new packages. I only had the oss and oss_update repositories, so the process I followed was:

```
sudo zypper rr oss
sudo zypper rr oss_update
sudo zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/oss/suse/ oss
sudo zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.3/oss/ oss_update

sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper up
```

To make sure this works for your version, find the version number of your system, and substitute it into the above URLs in the place of `42.3`. (You can make sure the URLs are valid by opening them in a browser.) You can see the version number in the output of the following command:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: In my case I also needed to change the priority (`zypper mr -p 99 reponame1 reponame2 reponameN `) of some repos: higher for some custom ones and lower for the default ones, in order to resolve the correct packages that I needed.

Comment: sudo zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/openSUSE-current/repo/oss oss

Answer (score 4):

For Leap 15.0 remove (suse/ from distribution link):

```
sudo zypper rr oss
sudo zypper rr oss_update

sudo zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/ oss
sudo zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/oss/ oss_update

sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper up
```